# Not able to save metadata through Groovy

Tags: groovy

We are migrating content from Sitecore to AEM.

For this below is the one Sitecore content  json

```
"topicBody": [
{
"itemId": "84dbfa1a",
"itemUrl": "",
"itemName": "Test Defect-Treatment",
"__typename": "TreatmentConcept",
"templateId": "c51297ec",
"pocId": "TXC-20096525",
"conceptBody": [
{
"itemId": "54ceda8a",
"itemName": "Test Defect-Closure",
"templateId": "d1a1f112",
"__typename": "KmSection",
"pocId": "SEC-2009",
"title": "Closure"
},
{
"itemId": "84134c21",
"itemName": "Test Defect-Patient Observation",
"templateId": "d1a1f112",
"__typename": "KmSection",
"pocId": "SEC-2006",
"title": "Observation"
}
],
"title": "Treatment",
"type": "",
"workflowItemManager": "mfad\\ALS07"
},
{
"itemId": "01ffe5c6",
"itemUrl": "",
"itemName": "Test Defect-Patient Considerations",
"__typename": "ConditionPatientConsiderationsConcept",
"templateId": "69265f07",
"pocId": "PTC-20117566",
"conceptBody": [
{
"itemId": "3a4f77ab",
"itemName": "Test Defect-Endocarditis Prophylaxis",
"templateId": "d1a1f112",
"__typename": "KmSection",
"pocId": "SEC-20096528",
"title": "Endocarditis prophylaxis"
}
],
"title": "Patient considerations",
"type": "",
"workflowItemManager": "mfad\\ALS07"
}
],
```

********************************* GROOVY SCRIPT **************************

I have written the below script for setting the metadata after creation of ditamap.

```
 def createADitaMap(title, topicBody){
        CreateDitaTopic topic = new CreateDitaTopic()
        try {
            def topicBodyItemTitle = title
            def newTopicPath
 
            if(type == "CPM"){
                JcrUtil.createPath(globalConfigurations.reuseLibraryCpmMaps+"/"+topicBodyItemTitle, JcrResourceConstants.NT_SLING_FOLDER, JcrResourceConstants.NT_SLING_FOLDER, session, true)
                newTopicPath = globalConfigurations.reuseLibraryCpmMaps+"/"+topicBodyItemTitle+"/"+topicBodyItemTitle+".ditamap"
            }else {
                JcrUtil.createPath(globalConfigurations.ameDitaMapBaseFolderPath+"/"+baseFolderForPoc+"/mapsandTopics", JcrResourceConstants.NT_SLING_FOLDER, JcrResourceConstants.NT_SLING_FOLDER, session, true)
                newTopicPath = globalConfigurations.ameDitaMapBaseFolderPath+"/"+baseFolderForPoc+"/mapsandTopics/"+topicBodyItemTitle+".ditamap"
            }
 
            def lbMapnode = resourceResolver.getResource(newTopicPath)
            if(null == lbMapnode) {
topic.create(session, title, newTopicPath, globalConfigurations.clinicalKnowledgeditaMapTemplatePath, resourceResolver, true)
def metadataNode = session.getNode(newTopicPath + "/jcr:content/metadata")
//out.println "metadataNode for updateDitaMetaDataForAME: ${metadataNode}"
if (metadataNode != null) {
metadataNode.setProperty("dc:title", topicBodyItemTitle)
metadataNode.setProperty("mc:assignedEditor", topicBody.assignedEditor)
metadataNode.setProperty("mc:PocId", topicBody.pocId)
}
                
            }
            session.save()
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) { /* Handling transitive API exception. */
            out.println "NullPointer Exception during topic creation in createADitaMap ${npe.getMessage()}"
        }catch (Exception e) {
            out.println "Exception during topic creation in createADitaMap ${e}"
        }
    }
```

Here my metadata is not saving and not working. I am getting the topicBodyItemTitle value dynamically. But metadata is not saving and also it should save like if TOPICBODY title is topicBodyItemTitle  then it should save the metadata related to topicbody and not conceptbody. I am not able to achieve this. Can somebody please help me here.

Thanks in advance.